# How do I modify all values for a column quickly in a migration?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a Message table with a number column. I want to add "++" to the beginning of each string in the number column. I don't think I can use update_all since each value for each row will be different. I tried doing Message.find_each, modifying the current value to have "++" in front and then saving, but it is taking forever to migrate (1 million + rows).

Is there a faster way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what about using simple raw mysql?

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.excute("UPDATE messages set `number` = CONCAT('++', `number`)")
```

it should be really fast

Answer (score 1):

I would try this. Maybe it's fast enough?

```
Message.find_in_batches.each do |batch|
  batch.each do |msg|
    msg.update_column :number, "++#{msg.number}"
  end
end
```

This will prevent loading each record individually, rather in batches (of 500 by default?). And then update column will avoid any of the Rails after hooks. If you want to record this as an update, you might want to set the `:updated_at` to `Time.now` too—something I always forget.

Or. Are some of the `number` values the same? Maybe you could group by rows that have the same value and do `update_all` on those?

Comment: This seems to be working pretty well, however, I put a counter to see where out of the 1 million messages the migration is, and it seems to significantly slow down around 300k. It took 10 seconds to do the first 300k messages and now it is taking exponentially more time for each 10k after the first 300k

Comment: Maybe there's some weird memory leak in Rails? Maybe after each batch try: `GC.start` to run the Garbage Collector.

Comment: tried that...still slows to a crawl after 300k messages.

Comment: Can you figure out if the slowness is on each lookup (db offset) or on the `update_column`? I imagine it's on the former.

Comment: I think it's the same problem that you get when you're paginating on large data sets. It has to do an offset and then a count. Updating now...

Comment: How do I figure out if it's on each lookup? (I assume you're right, that's the problem, not the update_column since update_column runs very fast for the first 300k records)

Comment: You could put a log before the `batch.each` and then one before the `msg.update_column`. I imagine the latter will move at the normal speed each time and the former will get slower.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72621/discussion-between-matthew-berman-and-evanbikes).

Answer (score 1):

You want to batch the results and iterate through if you *really* have to do this. Why do you have to put a "++" in front anyway? It may prevent you from incrementing and you could always create a helper method which prefixes the value instead.